# How is a char array useful in identifying anagrams?

Tags: c, anagram

I'm trying to write an anagram program, so I found the following example to start.  But I can't quite figure out the line, `first[a[i]-'a']++;`  What's the point of incrementing the value of this char array here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int check_anagram(char a[], char b[]){
   int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, i = 0;

   while (a[i] != '\0'){
      first[a[i]-'a']++;   //  ??????????
      i++;
   }
   i = 0;
   while (b[i] != '\0'){
      second[b[i]-'a']++;
      i++;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){
      if (first[i] != second[i])
         return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}

int main(){
   char a[100], b[100];
   int flag;

   printf("Enter first string\n");
   gets(a);
   printf("Enter second string\n");
   gets(b);

   flag = check_anagram(a, b);
   if (flag == 1)
      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are anagrams.\n", a, b);
   else
      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are not anagrams.\n", a, b);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`first[]` and `second[]` are arrays containing a count of which letters occur in the first and second strings respectively.

So `first[a[i]-'a']++` is incrementing the count for a given letter. Initially, all the letters (with indexes 0 - 25, corresponding to the letters a-z) will have count = 0. As you step through each letter in the string, you increment the count of that particular letter.

The result is a **[histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)** of [letter frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) for the whole word.

Doing this for each of the two strings (a and b) allows you to tell whether they are anagrams of each other: any pair of words which are anagrams will have identical histograms.

Examples:

```
""         -> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
"CAT"      -> [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
"ESTRANGE" -> [1,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
"SERGEANT" -> [1,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] // same as "ESTRANGE"
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
  first[a[i]-'a']++;
```

assumes that the value of `a[i]` is in the range `a-z`. When `a[i]` is `a`, it increments `first[0]`. When `a[i]` is `z`, it increments `first[25]`. By the end of the loop

```
while (a[i] != '\0'){
  first[a[i]-'a']++;   //  ??????????
  i++;
}
```

the array `first` contains the count of the letters `a-z` in the array `a`.